How can I solve the problem of mapbox in android studio
While I am trying to make a bus tracking app, there is a problem occurring in mapbox. Below is my code:
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.Mapbox;

import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.geometry.LatLng;

import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView;

import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapboxMap;

import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;

import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.Style;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MapView mapView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Mapbox.getInstance(this, getString(R.string.mapbox_access_token));
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mapView = findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(MapboxMap mapboxMap) {
                mapboxMap.setStyle(Style.MAPBOX_STREETS, new Style.OnStyleLoaded() {
                    @Override
                    public void onStyleLoaded(Style style) {
                        // Map is ready
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mapView.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mapView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mapView.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        mapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mapView.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mapView.onLowMemory();
    }
}

this is the problem that is shown:

Cannot resolve symbol 'Mapbox'

I checked the dependencies and they all are correct.
When I tried to run the app the import files for Mapbox is not staring, also there is a third party error shown in build.gradle when i put Mapbox
